# Jenkins environment: tool name

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, cicd

In my organization we use Jenkins as a CD tool, but due to some reasons we are switching to Giltab CI/CD right now. I am transferring pipeline from Jenkins to Gitlab and faced with some problems. For example, there are lines of code that I do not understand and can not find any docs describing it:

```
environment {
        SBT_HOME = tool name: 'sbt-1.2.6', type: 'org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.SbtPluginBuilder$SbtInstallation'
        PATH = "${env.SBT_HOME}/bin:${env.PATH}"
}
```

I do not understand how the `tool name: 'smth' type: 'smth'` works. If I am getting it right `tool` is a Jenkins' built-in stuff, but I can not reproduce the result of it.

Does anyone know how it works and what is a result of this function? And how to reproduce it Gitlab or may be in Linux CLI after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Javadoc](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/sbt/org/jvnet/hudson/plugins/SbtPluginBuilder.SbtInstallation.html), the tool is the plugin, [SBT](https://plugins.jenkins.io/sbt/), Scala Build Tool.

`SBT_HOME = tool name: 'sbt-1.2.6', type: 'org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.SbtPluginBuilder$SbtInstallation'`

This first line determines the installation path for the [tool](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#tool-use-a-tool-from-a-predefined-tool-installation) configured  your Global Tool Configuration (`${JENKINS_URL}/configureTools/`) ([tutorial](http://www.mtitek.com/tutorials/tools/jenkins/configure-tools.php)), labeled `sbt-1.2.6`.

The second line adds that to the `PATH`, presumably for use in the builds steps.

So, you need to have [Scala Build Tool](https://www.scala-sbt.org/) installed in your Gitlab CI/CD environment and available in the `PATH`. That's it.